# how to monitor/modify/cancel http request sent by webbrowser control?

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, httprequest

I'm using webbrowser control in my program. I want to cancel/modify certain http request made by the webbrowser. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157329/Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control

It has example code in C#, but the Webbrowser Control is COM, and interceptor DLL is also ATL COM, so I think it will work for you.

1. You may create a HTTP proxy in your application and use it to intercept the traffic.